# DNS Lookup Timeout Error - Change Resolv.conf?

Tags: domain-name-system, timeout

Google webmaster tools tells me that I have DNS lookup timeout errors. My nameservers and bind are configured properly and intodns.com reports no errors.

**Question:** Can I simply change the nameservers in /etc/resolv.conf to use the resolvers from OpenDNS or could this break my server?

Could it be a firewall issue? I am using CSF firewall at the moment.

Comment: When asking questions that require troubleshooting DNS it is **incredibly helpful** to know the domain name in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Google's telling you that you're having timeouts, it's not your server's DNS config, it's the authoritative DNS servers for you domain.

Check that all the servers in your domain's registration record are still valid and hosting working copies of your domain's zone.

Comment: How exactly would I check the domain records? A simple who.is query lists my nameservers, but not more. How can you be so sure that my hosting provider did not misconfigure their resolvers causing a DNS timeout when the domain gets translated.

Comment: When I do a nslookup I also get an authoratative answer